# I have reached the question limit but I haven't asked any questions

Tags: support, monthly-question-limit

I just got a Stack Exchange account a week or so ago, and I have not posted any questions. I went to post my first question and I got a message saying, "You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period." I haven't posted a single question yet. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: Do you share your IP address?

Comment: Also, check the related questions on the right.

Comment: I think you just did.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: He means on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My awesome sense of humor isn't going to be fully appreciated until someone invents the Sarcasm font...

Comment: @JohnnyBones: [Here you go](http://glennmcanally.com/sarcastic/).